# iOS Google Maps - GMSUserAddedPlace backend error

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, sdk

I am trying to add a place to Google Maps in ios using [GMSUserAddedPlace](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_user_added_place.html#a82d4372c3a1426c192c89df3409b32d7) but I am getting a 'backend error' all the time.

Code:

```
      GMSUserAddedPlace *addPlace = [[GMSUserAddedPlace alloc] init];
        addPlace.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(postCoordinates.latitude, postCoordinates.longitude);
        addPlace.address = address;
        addPlace.types = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"food", @"restaurant", @"establishment", nil];
        addPlace.name = textField.text;


        [_placesClient addPlace:addPlace callback:^(GMSPlace *place, NSError *error) {

            if (error != nil) {
               //here I get a google error which is titled 'backend error'
                NSLog(@"User Added Place error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                return;
            }

            NSLog(@"Added place %@", place.placeId);

        }];
```

Comment: You can try to change your `types` array to just only item. (ex, `addPlace.types = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"food",, nil];` Because the Places Add sometimes does not work, if your place has multiple types.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Thanks. I reduced the types array to one type and now it works.